# Highlight menu icon when on that page using React/ Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby.js to build a site. It works very similarly to React.js.

I have a side menu. I would like the icons on this menu to be highlighted when the user is on the respective page. Gatsby has an '[activeStyle'](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) option but this is not working for me. The icon still remains white when I am on the respective page.

My gatsby code using activeStyle looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar_button">
          <Link to="/about">
            <i>
              <FiUser size={22} activeStyle={{ color: "blue" }} />
            </i>
            <p>ABOUT</p>
          </Link>
</div>
```

'FiUser' is the name of the icon I am using (with react-icons).

If I change 'activeStyle' to just 'style', the icon does change to blue - just not with 'activeStyle'.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to whats going wrong?

[image: side menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activeStyle` and `activeClassName` are supposed to be used on the `Link` component itself, not on it's children.

```
<div class="sidebar_button">
      <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active-link">
        <i>
          <FiUser size={22} className="user-icon" />
        </i>
        <p>ABOUT</p>
      </Link>
</div>
```

The `i` and `FiUser` should not have any attributes that would override this style.

On styling:

```
.user-link {
  color: blue;
}
.active .user-link {
  color: white;
}
```

[Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#add-custom-styles-for-the-currently-active-link)

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you! I had some overriding css colourings. How do I choose the 'not active' colour of the icons if my css overrides the activeStyle property?

Comment: you can use the `activeClassName` instead of `activeStyle` to override the styles on child

Comment: Hmm, these don't seem to work on my end but what does seem to work is: .active {
  color: #70a260;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

Comment: Did you add `user-link` as `className`, also your current style would change the color of all `a` tags to white.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get it working - I have changed the class name and it works as far as highlighting the correct page but I still cannot choose the colour of the default icon without targeting 'a' in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Using Boy With Silver Wings answer with some modifications, I found what worked for me was:

```
<div class="sidebar_button">
    <Link to="/" activeClassName="user-link">
        <i>
            <TiHomeOutline size={22} className="user-icon" />
        </i>
        <p className="user-text">HOME</p>
    </Link>
</div>
```

And for my CSS:

```
.user-icon {
  color: #d8d8d8;
}

.user-text {
  color: #d8d8d8;
}

.user-link .user-icon {
  color: #97b27b;
}

.user-link .user-text {
  color: #97b27b;
}
```

This generates exactly what I was looking for. I hope this can help someone else.

E.g when on the about/ 'silhouette' page it looks like this:

[image]